# Getting parse error unexpected '")' in a PHP file…

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea why am I getting that error at the end of this line

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email,Date,Gender,WardType)
         VALUES ('$Name','$Email','$Date','$Gender','$WardType')");
```

Suppose the closing was supposed to be such? or `');` but they all giving me the error.

Comment: What is that extra parenthesis doing there in the end?

Answer (score -1):

Try This and used concatenation

```
//$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email,Date,Gender,WardType) VALUES
//("'.$Name.'","'.$Email.'","'.$Date.'","'.$Gender.'","'.$WardType.'")";
```

Use this one now:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email,Date,Gender,WardType) VALUES 
('".$Name."','".$Email."','".$Date."','".$Gender."','".$WardType."')";
```

There was a trailing `)` at the end.

Comment: That leads me to this

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$Name.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\insert.php on line 23

Comment: Overal here is the whole thing

Comment: $Name = $_POST['username'];
    $Email= $_POST['email'];
    $Email= $_POST['date'];
    $Email= $_POST['gender'];
    $Email= $_POST['wardtype'];
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email,Date,Gender,WardType) VALUES ("'.$Name.'","'.$Email.'","'.$Date.'","'.$Gender.'","'.$WardType.'")";

Comment: @PeterHelao I have edited the answer please have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra closing parethensis `)`

Should be like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email,Date,Gender,WardType) VALUES ('$Name','$Email','$Date','$Gender','$WardType')";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Name,Email,Date,Gender,WardType) VALUES ('$Name','$Email','$Date','$Gender','$WardType')";
```

You had a closed parenthesis in the end but it was never opened. Try this one it should work for you. All brackets/parenthesis must open and close if you forget one opened or close one that pairs nowhere you get this error.